# Android independent services how to?

Tags: android, service, apk

I was wondering if there is a way to create a service that will run as it's own process independent of an activity.  I would want to service to run in the foreground so it would not be killed and also accessible to other .apk that wish to use it.  How can I do this?  I've read so much that its made me a little more confused then I initially was.  Any help would be much appreciated.

To clarify.  I would like to run a service that can communicate with many .apk's.  It is an in-house application with no market value.  What I am trying to do is make service that .apk can register there content providers with so all .apk's using this service have a list of all other .apk's content providers to use as pleased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are by their nature independent of Activities. You don't need one to run the other.  Services always run in the background and usually don't get killed unless they take too many resources.

Depending on the type of interaction you want between the Service and  Activities you'll need to define the appropriate intents or maybe use a ContentProvider.

**UPDATE**:

In the case you described above, simply have each content provider register with service using an intent that specifies the URI needed to access that content provider. The service would then keep a list of all registered content providers and their URI's.

When a new activity wants to get a list of all available ContentProviders it can query the  service with an intent asking for a list of providers. The service would then respond with an intent that would contain the list of providers and URIs.

Using this information the individual activities could then decide which content providers they want to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this?

You don't, insofar as you do not need it to be "as it's own process". Just start up the service via `startService()` and have the service call `startForeground()`. It can be part of the same process as the activity, and the user will be able to navigate away from that activity if desired and the service will remain running.

> I would want to service to run in the foreground so it would not be killed

Note that users are still welcome to get rid of your service. `startForeground()` will reduce the odds of Android getting rid of the service on its own.

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I have done what you are saying.  After a little more searching I think what I am looking for is a Remote Service that will run independent of the .apk.  I want the service to continue to run even if the application is killed (by the user or by android).  So would using a Remote Service Accomplish this?

Comment: @jjNford: "After a little more searching I think what I am looking for is a Remote Service that will run independent of the .apk." -- that is highly unlikely and definitely bad for the user. Please reconsider. " I want the service to continue to run even if the application is killed (by the user or by android)." -- fortunately, this is impossible. "So would using a Remote Service Accomplish this?" -- no.